# react-sortable-tree not working on react 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the example of react-sortable-tree but it's not working on **react 17.0.1**.

When I'm using react 16.14.0, it has no error and working fine.

**List of Errors:**

- Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
  at findHostInstanceWithWarning
- Uncaught TypeError: this.clearMonitorSubscription is not a function
  at ScrollingComponent.componentWillUnmount
- The above error occurred in the <Scrolling(List)> component:

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css'
import SortableTree from 'react-sortable-tree'
class Areas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      treeData: [
        { title: 'Chicken', children: [{ title: 'Egg' }] },
        { title: 'Fish', children: [{ title: 'fingerline' }] }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <SortableTree
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me setting `isVirtualized` property of `SortableTree` component to `false` as a temporary solution worked out ([link](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree/issues/821#issuecomment-735045863)). Warning: it disables auto-scrolling while dragging, and scrolling to the `searchFocusOffset`.

Also there is a solution using `patch-package` https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree/issues/821#issuecomment-766860082

Corresponding issue: https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree/issues/821

PR to watch: https://github.com/frontend-collective/frontend-collective-react-dnd-scrollzone/pull/80

Comment: worked for me with set `isVirtualized` to `false`. thank you

Comment: Yeah worked for me as well, strange that this issue is opened since last year and not yet been fixed

Comment: Unfortunately looks like Abandonware, last updated 2,3,4 years ago...