# react-sortable-tree: code doesn't display anything

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, frontend, treeview

I'm working with reactjs 17 but I don't know why this code doesn't display anything.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SortableTree from 'react-sortable-tree';
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css';

export default class Tree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      treeData: [
        { title: 'Chicken', children: [{ title: 'Egg' }] },
        { title: 'Fish', children: [{ title: 'fingerline' }] },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <SortableTree
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you are rendering `Tree` component?

Comment: import './App.css';
import Tree from './Tree';

function App () {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tree />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: Set outer div style as `<div style={{ height: 400, width: 500, border: '1px solid red' }}>` Do you see the div itself?

Comment: yes i see the div but it's empty inside

Comment: the same is happening to me :C any update?

Comment: my problem was solved ...my problem was the version of reactjs.. sortable tree doesnt work with react 17 when i change the project to version 16 it works very well

Comment: react-sortable-tree not working on react 17.0.1 see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180124/react-sortable-tree-not-working-on-react-17-0-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180124/react-sortable-tree-not-working-on-react-17-0-1)

Answer (score 2):

Use following package for React 17+

[react-sortable-tree for React 17+](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nosferatu500/react-sortable-tree)